# Printing string inside of an integer array

Tags: arrays, c, string, integer

I am trying to print a string in between integers. How should it be done

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution without an array:

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        switch (i) {
          case 10:  printf("ten ");     break;
          case 20:  printf("twenty ");  break;
          case 30:  printf("thirty ");  break;
          case 40:  printf("forty ");   break;
          case 50:  printf("fifty ");   break;
          case 60:  printf("sixty ");   break;
          case 70:  printf("seventy "); break;
          case 80:  printf("eighty ");  break;
          case 90:  printf("ninety ");  break;
          case 100: printf("one hundred ");  break;
          default:  printf("%d ", i % 10);   break;
        }
    }
```

Or using an array for the strings:

```
    const char *tens[] = {
          "zero", "ten", "twenty", "thirty", "forty",
          "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety",
          "one hundred" };
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        if (i % 10 == 0) {
            printf("%s ", tens[i / 10]);
        } else {
            printf("%d ", i % 10);
        }
    }
```

Comment: But your code doesn't store anything into an array. (I'm not completely sure *what* those stored values should be, though.)

Comment: @AdrianMole: the array seems superfluous :)

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the logic much the same as in your code (especially the resetting of the stored/output numbers whenever a multiple of 10 is reached), we can rewrite the code as shown below:

```cpp
#include<stdio.h>

#define limit 100

int main()
{
    const char* tens[] = { "ten", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety", "a hundred" };
    int A[limit];
    for (int i = 0, j = 1; i < limit; i++, j++) {
        A[i] = j;
        if (A[i] % 10 == 0) {
            A[i] = 1;
            printf("%s ", tens[i/10]);
            j = 0; // Reset to ZERO because of the loop increment
        }
        else { // Don't print number if we have shown the word version
            printf("%d ", A[i]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The main idea is to create an array of the words to be printed when appropriate; that will be whenever the remainder of a division by 10 is zero (the `A[i] % 10 == 0` condition). The index of which word to print will be given by dividing the running `i` value by 10 (making use of the fact the integer division truncates).

Also note some other changes I have made:

1. The `j` value should be reset to **zero** (not 1) when a word is printed, because it will be subsequently incremented (to 1) at the end of that loop.
2. I have moved the 'normal' integer printing into an `else` block, because your desired output doesn't print the number when it prints the word.

However, if you want to keep the original number sequence (i.e. 1 thru 100) in the array, then you can remove the `j` variable completely and print the value of `A[i] % 10` when displaying the numerical value:

```cpp
#include<stdio.h>
#define limit 100

int main()
{
    const char* tens[] = { "ten", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety", "a hundred" };
    int A[limit];
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        A[i] = i + 1;
        if (A[i] % 10 == 0) {
            printf("%s ", tens[i/10]);
        }
        else { // Don't print number if we have shown the word version
            printf("%d ", A[i] % 10);
        }
    }
    // Original array keeps the proper values ...
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        printf("%d ", A[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```