# How to print numbers from 1 to 19 but numbers above 9 should just print one digit?

Tags: c

How can I print numbers from 1 to the limit the user puts in? But above 9 the 10 just print a green 1 and 1,2,3,4,.. and then for 20 a green 2 and so on ...

like this:
-123456789***1***12345689***2***12345....-
and so on.

My current code:

```
  int o;
  do {
    for(o = 0; o < width+2;o++) {
      if(o != 0 || o != width+1)
        if(o % 10 != 0)
          printf("%d", o);
        else
          printf("\033[032m%d\033[0m", o);
    }                                       
  } while(o<width);

  printf("-");
```

[Current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjFiu.png)

It should start to print with zero and end with 19 (because the player here input was 19).

Comment: you can `print(number % 10) /* <== THIS IS NOT C SYNTAX!! */` to print the "last" digit of the number.

Comment: Looks very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72249779/10871073) ... and the answers there can be trivially adapted to your problem.

Comment: I beg of you.  Please don't use `o` as a variable name.

Comment: @Catty_cat "like this: -123456789112345689212345...." and "start to print with zero" contradict.  Please clarify the first digit.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps as simple as

```
// Iterate to `width`
for (int i = 0; i <= width; i++) {
  if (i % 10 || i == 0) {
    printf("%d", i % 10); // Print only the one's digit.
  } else {
    printf("\033[032m%d\033[0m", (i/10)%10); // Print only the ten's digit.
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you, but how can i fix this, the ' _ ' symbol is now before the last number but it should be behind

Comment: @Catty_cat ' _ ' is never printed in your question nor current output so your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72463328/how-to-print-numbers-from-1-to-19-but-numbers-above-9-should-just-print-one-digi/72463573?noredirect=1#comment128011035_72463573) is unclear..  Please append a [mcve].